# Populate select with optgroup using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to programmatically populate a `select` tag with `optgroup` and `option` tags using jQuery.  I've got the code debugged using JSHint (at least it says there's no errors), and for the most part it does at the very least put up the select box.  However it's not putting the data in.

Code: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39xkzcck/)

Data: [JSON File](https://sow.zhivco.com/assets/json/titles.json)

I would like it to output something along the lines of:

```
<select id="profile_title" name="profile_title">
  <optgroup label="Backers">
    <option value="civi">Civilian</option>
    <option value="scot">Scout</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Other Titles">
    <option value="apex">Apex Predator</option>
    <option value="etc">Etc etc..</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Am I just trying to got one or more levels too deep?  Oh, and the JSON file I've checked with [The JSON Validator](http://jsonlint.com/).

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Check the console; you're being blocked by the Same Origin Policy. If the domain you're calling does not support JSONP or CORS you cannot do this using JS alone.

Comment: ok, ty. I'll upload it to my server directly and test it there.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, the line `$.appendTo("#somewhere");` should be removed. It's not doing anything :)

Comment: The "JSON File" link is now dead.  This is why questions should be self-contained :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code worked for me once I removed $.appendTo('#somewhere')

JS that worked for me:

```
$.getJSON('https://sow.zhivco.com/assets/json/titles.json', {
  format: "JSON"
}).done(function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(i, optgroups) {
    $.appendTo("#somewhere");
    $.each(optgroups, function(groupName, options) {
     var $optgroup = $("<optgroup>", {
        label: groupName
      });
      $optgroup.appendTo('#somewhere');
      $.each(options, function(j, option) {
        var $option = $("<option>", {
          text: option.title,
          value: option.value
        });
        $option.appendTo($optgroup);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

[Here is a working codepen.](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/EPGXMd)

I had to load your JSON into a variable in the codepen, because the server it is hosted on does not support [CORS issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

If you are having CORS issues, there are plenty of answered questions on this site that can help you.

Comment: Thank you!  Glad to see it was only a CORS issue, like you stated.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

send ajax only to your server

and on server do

```
    echo file_get_contents('https://sow.zhivco.com/assets/json/titles.json')
```

or use CURL

!!! cross domain ajax is no good !!!

Comment: Thank you for helping me. :)